# How to Create Websetup for Clickonce type windows forms application by publishing it to some folder

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

Trying to publish a click once type app to a local directory and create a websetup with the published contents- so that i can give tat setup to install in two different servers. but as the publishing wizard takes a URL - separate setup is required for each server. Is there any way that i can create a single setup which i can use it in two servers..?

Answer (score 0):

The URL for setup.exe is only for the purpose of bootstrapping. What I found is that the bootstrapper that gets created with your deployment manifest ('setup.exe') is designed for a web-published application. 
If your clickonce publish will be installed on intranet servers, you can't use out of the box bootstrapper. You may write your own or build a seperate setup project for bootstrapping and calling the .application from the installed server when the pre requisites where installed.
If you don't rely on pre requisites and you can ask users to make sure they have the right CLR version, you don't need the setup.exe at all.